# Node.js, Socket.IO, Express: Should app logic be in socket handlers or REST api?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, socket.io, api-design

I'm planning a non-trivial realtime chat platform. The app has several types of resources: Users, Groups, Channels, Messages. There are roughly 20 types of realtime events having to do with these resources: for instance, submitting a message, a user connecting or disconnecting, a user joining a group, a moderator kicking a user from a group, etc...

Overall, I see two paths to organizing all this complexity.

The first is to build a REST API to manage the resources. For instance, to send a message, POST to `/api/v1/messages`. Or, to kick a user from a group, POST to `/api/v1/group/:group_id/kick/`. Then, from within the Express route handler, call `io.emit` (made accessible through res.locals) with the updated data to notify all related clients. In this case, clients talk to the server through HTTP and the server notifies clients through socket.io.

The other option is to not have a rest API at all, and handle all events through socket.IO. For instance, to send a message, emit a `SEND_MESSAGE` event. Or, to kick a user, emit a `KICK_USER` event. Then, from within the socket.io event handler, call `io.emit` with the updated data to notify all clients.

Yet another option is to have certain actions handled by a REST API, others by socket.IO. For instance, to get all messages, `GET api/v1/channel/:id/messages`. But to post a message, emit `SEND_MESSAGE` to the socket.

Which is the most suitable option? How do I determine which actions need to be sent thorough an API, and which need to be sent through socket.io? Is it better not to have a REST API for this type of application?

---

Some of my thoughts so far, nothing conclusive:

Advantages of REST API over the socket.io-only approach:

- Easier to organize hierarchically, more modular
- Easier to test
- More robust and elegant
- Simpler auth implementation with middleware

Disadvantages of REST API over the socket.io-only approach:

- Slightly less performant ([source](http://blog.arungupta.me/rest-vs-websocket-comparison-benchmarks))
- Since a socket connection needs to be open anyways, why not use it for everything?
- Slightly harder to manage on the client side.

---

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieve this using sockets.

Why because a chat application will be having dozens of actions, like ..

***'STARTS_TYPING', 'STOPS_TYPING', 'SEND_MESSAGE', 'RECIVE_MESSAGE',...***

Accommodating all these features using rest api's will generate a complex system which lacks performance.

Also concept of rooms in socket.io simplifies lot of headache regarding group chat implementation.

So its better to build everything based on sockets[socket.io or web cluster].

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found to solve this problem.

The key mistake in my question was that I assumed a rest API and websockets were mutually exclusive, because I intended on integrating the business and database logic directly in express routes and socket.io handlers. Thus, choosing between socket.io and http was important, because it would influence the core business logic of my app.

Instead, it shouldn't matter which transport to use. The business logic has to be independent from the transport logic, in its own module.

To do this, I developed a service layer that handles CRUD tasks, but also more specific tasks such as authentication. Then, this service layer can be easily consumed from either or both express routes and socket.io handlers.

In the end, this architecture allowed me not to easily switch between transport technologies.